# Export Mac App From Windows Solution

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I recently installed Visual Studio For Mac and was expecting I would need to rewrite an exe I wrote in C# for Windows.  Surprisingly, I opened the Windows solution in VS Mac and it ran without issue.  The problem is, building the solution still exports an .exe file.  Since I can run the app through VS Mac, I thought it might be possible to export the solution as a stand-alone Mac app.  Is this possible and, if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score -1):

You're wrong about vs for Mac, and she can't turn the original C# project into an MAC available application. If you want to make an application available under Mac, you should re create a Xamarin.Forms project with vs for Mac, and then go back to design. This process relies on Xamarin and mono, which you should know clearly.
Xamarin reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/

Comment: How am I wrong about VSfM?  It can definitely run my Windows app through the debugger.  Also the link you provided is dead.